# Dynamic javascript graph

Tags: javascript, php, canvasjs

I has downloaded graph from https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/multi-series-chart/. 
I implemented in my project. Graph is not working if value is absent. Below is my code

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: "Your position with top two students"
    }, 
    axisY:{
        title: "Subjects number based on 100"
    },
    toolTip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend:{
        cursor:"pointer",
        itemclick: toggleDataSeries
    },
    data: [{
        type: "spline",
        name: "<?php echo $topper1['name'] ?>",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: [
            { label: "<?php echo $subjectt['sub1'] ?>", y: <?php echo $topper1['sub1'] ?> },
            { label: "<?php echo $subjectt['sub2'] ?>", y: <?php echo $topper1['sub2'] ?> },
            { label: "<?php echo $subjectt['sub3'] ?>", y: <?php echo $topper1['sub3'] ?> },
            { label: "<?php echo $subjectt['sub4'] ?>", y: <?php echo $topper1['sub4'] ?> },
            { label: "<?php echo $subjectt['sub5'] ?>", y: <?php echo $topper1['sub5'] ?> },
            { label: "<?php echo $subjectt['sub6'] ?>", y: <?php echo $topper1['sub6'] ?> }, 
            { label: "<?php echo $subjectt['sub7'] ?>", y: <?php echo $topper1['sub7'] ?> },
            { label: "<?php echo $subjectt['sub8'] ?>", y: <?php echo $topper1['sub8'] ?> },
            { label: "<?php echo $subjectt['sub9'] ?>", y: <?php echo $topper1['sub9'] ?> }, 
            { label: "<?php echo $subjectt['sub10'] ?>", y: <?php echo $topper1['sub10'] ?> }
        ]
    }]
});

chart.render();

function toggleDataSeries(e) {
    if(typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
    }
    else {
        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
    }
    chart.render();
}

}
</script>
```

**what I want**
If $subjectt['sub10'] value is null then that value do not reflect on graph.And other reflect.

Comment: you can modify dataPoints using php `if` statement to check null value. like `<?php if($subjectt['sub10']!=null){ ?> { label: "<?php echo $subjectt['sub10'] ?>", y: <?php echo $topper1['sub10'] ?> } <?php} ?>`

Comment: Please checkout CanvasJS PHP Gallery (https://canvasjs.com/php-charts/) for more similar examples including chart from json/csv/xml, dynamic charts, chart from database along with source code which you can modify as per your requirements